# Are spark dataframes distributed?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm converting a batch operation to a spark job with the intention of running in in AWS EMR; the core of this job is a join between two reasonably large data sets.

The core of the operation is a join:

```
table_1: loaded from json file_1
table_2: loaded from parquet file_2
joined_table = table_1.join(table_2)
   .map(some_data_transformations)

store_it_off(joined_table)
```

From the google definitions, a dataFrame is a tabular structure, and an Rdd is distributed; however, I've seen other notes that dataFrames are implemented based on Rdds.  Are dataframes distributed? Are they distributed only after certain steps to parallelize them?

Comment: RDD API is only for compatibility. You should be using Spark 2.x with Dataset (if using latest Spark)

Comment: "The Dataset API is available in Scala and Java. Python does not have the support for the Dataset API. But due to Python’s dynamic nature, many of the benefits of the Dataset API are already available (i.e. you can access the field of a row by name naturally row.columnName). The case for R is similar."  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes .   I'm using pyspark

Comment: I think Dataframe is distributed. Its former name is SchemaRDD, a kind of RDD too.

Answer (score 2):

yes Spark dataFrames are distributed 
from spark the difinitive guide :

> ..spark dataFrame can span thousands of computers.

however this is only available in scala and java, 
from the same book :

> ... Python/R DataFrames exist on one machine rather than multiple machines

Comment: I believe what they probably meant in that book is that Pandas dataframes exist on a single machine (that's what I think they mean by Python DataFrames). And that is the case for R dataframes as well. I don't think they meant that there's a limitation specific to the Spark dataframes you create with PySpark.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional yeah I think So also, because from the official documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) it is said that : "...Python does not have the support for the Dataset API. But due to Python’s dynamic nature, many of the benefits of the Dataset API are already available ."